# Pandas index returns value error: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 199 elements, new values have 200 elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have written this piece of code but when I try use Series function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

# example values
dates = np.asarray(pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=200))

# create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(200, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

print(df)
start_idx = np.where(dates>=np.datetime64(dt.datetime.strptime('2000-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d")))[0][-1]

dateIndex = df[0: start_idx+1].index
print(dateIndex)


historydict = {}
for i in range(3):
    returnHistory = pd.Series(df[i+1:start_idx+2]['A'])
    returnHistory.index = dateIndex
    # the above two periods assigned to date t, the returns lagged by i periods
    rname="Hist"+str(i+1)
    historydict[rname]=returnHistory
hDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(historydict)
print(hDataFrame)
```

historydict will be used to keep track of series for t-1, t-2, t-3, each will become a column in a dataframe but

```
returnHistory.index = dateIndex
```

Gives this error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 199 elements, new values have 200 elements
```

Comment: `temp` is `DataFrame`, what is reason for convert to `Series` ?

Comment: I updated the question. The problem is not the temp at all. I need to know why the series function gives this error

Answer (score 2):

At line

`returnHistory = pd.Series(temp)`

is a `pandas.DataFrame` object with shape `(199, 4)`. Try

`returnHistory = pd.Series(temp['A'])`

or other column.

Comment: That problem solved but another error occurred : ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 199 elements, new values have 200 elements on this line: returnHistory.index = dateIndex

Comment: @amin mohammadi I don't know what finally you want to do, but new problem caused by `returnHistory = pd.Series(df[i+1:start_idx+2])` statement. More precise - by `[i+1:start_idx+2]` index. After this operation `returnHistory` will have shape (199, 4), and `dateIndex` have shape (200, ).

Comment: historydict will be used to keep track of series for t-1, t-2, t-3, each will become a column in a dataframe